# Why the color of the text Sausage is red?

Tags: html, css

css and html are :

```css
#awesome .favorite:not(#awesome) .highlight {
    color: red;
}
#awesome .highlight:nth-of-type(1):nth-last-of-type(1) {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="shopping-list" id="awesome">
    <li><span>Milk</span></li>
    <li class="favorite" id="must-buy"><span class="highlight">Sausage</span></li>
</ul>
```

how the parser decides the color red applied to text sausage?

Comment: TL;DR : there is 2 ID in the first one so it will alwyas win (adding more duplicates ..)